# Two hosts under one domain and SEO

Tags: seo, domains

I have a currently live site running on PHP/Apache on a shared server.
And in the other side a new functionality, a web app,  based on nodejs that will run on google cloud. So both services will be not related and probably geographically distant.

I am considering if it will be worth and possible to keep the PHP one as it is during the first months of life of the new one.

The question is, how to have both under the same domain?. I am mostly concerned on SEO optimization as the new one should provide a "boost" of SEO

Possible solutions:

- A subdomain for the new stuff but I wonder how good or bad this may be in SEO terms.
- Load balancer. It looks more flexible, not sure if much complex.
- Reverse proxy?

Any thoughts?

EDIT
Reading about load balancers, there's an added factor, cost. It seems no big deal but one more aspect to consider.

Comment: Is the new stuff a replacement for the old stuff or is it new fresh content that will add to the old stuff?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It will add to the old stuff.

Comment: How is a "load balancer" a solution to this problem?

Comment: @MrWhite I am starting to learn about that but if I understand well a load balancer gets all the traffic to a domain and, by the rules it is configured, distributes the load among different services/hosts whatever with an URL, right?